# c# Declaring recordset variable equal to string from stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am converting previous classic asp in vb code to asp.net in c#. I am having trouble assigning a variable to the recordset stored procedure variable (objRs). I have tried setting it up as 
    `strap = objRs("strap");`
but that gives me an error on objRS "local variable ADODB.Recordset objRS - Method Delegate or Event is Expected"

I have tried it with brackets:
    `strap = objRs["strap"];`
which gives me the error on the second strap "Ambiguous indexer: ADODB.Fields Fields (in interface_Recordset); ADODB.Fields Fields (in interface_Recordset15); "" (in interface_Recordset20); "" (in interface_Recordset21); match"

I have also tried various Convert.ToString methods but was unsuccessful.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Common" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.EnterpriseServices" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" %>
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection;  
using ADODB;
<%  

%>
<!DOCTYPE html HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=9, IE=8, IE=10, IE=11" />

    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior on iOS devices--> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>My Mapping Application</title>
    <script runat="server">



    private void OpenConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        string txtTaxYear;
        //txtTaxYear;
        string webacct, strap, straptype = null, ownername, facetMap;

        txtTaxYear = Request.Form["ddlTaxYear"].Trim();
        webacct = Request.Form["txtAcct"].Trim();
        nhCd = Request.Form["nh_cd"].Trim();
        nhGrpCd = Request.Form["nh_grp_cd"].Trim();

        //var objConn = null;

        OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB; DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=XYZserver;UID=xyzuser;PWD=xyzpassword;DATABASE=xyzdatabase\" + (txtTaxYear + \";\")");

        objConn.Open();

        ADODB.Recordset objRs= new ADODB.RecordsetClass();

        //var objRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset");

        // -------------------------------------------------
        // Execute SQL Function to determine Property Type
        // -------------------------------------------------

        ADODB.Recordset rsRci= new ADODB.RecordsetClass();

        //var rsRci = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset");

        var mysql = ("select h_" + (txtTaxYear + (".dbo.hc_fn_rci(\'" + (webacct + "\') AS rci"))));


        //while (!(rsRci.State == 1))
        while (rsRci.State != (int) ConnectionState.Open)
            rsRci.Open(mysql, objConn);

        while ((!rsRci.BOF) & (!rsRci.EOF))
        {
            straptype == rsRci("rci");
            switch (straptype)
            {
                case null:
                    straptype = "N";
                    break;
                case "":
                    straptype = "B";
                    break;
            }
            rsRci.MoveNext();
        }


        object i;
        object j;
        strap = "";

        if ((straptype == "C"))
        {
            var strSql = ("EXEC hcad..sp_maps_HE_getSubjectAcctInfo \'" + (txtTaxYear + ("\', \'" + (webacct + "\', \'C\'"))));
            objRs.Open(strSql, objConn);
            if (!objRs.EOF)
            {               
                strap = objRs("strap");                
                ownerName = objRs("ownerName");
                siteAddr = objRs("site_addr");
                nhCd = objRs("nh_cd");
                yrImpr = objRs("yr_impr");
                dorCd = objRs("dor_cd");
                facetMap = objRs("facet_map").Substring(0, 4);                
            }
        }


        // -------------------------------------------------
        // Clean Up Objects
        // -------------------------------------------------
        if (rsRci.State == 1)
        {
            rsRci.Close();
        }

        if (objRs.State == 1)
        {
            objRs.Close();
        }


        rsRci = null;
        objRs = null;
        objConn = null;
    }
}

    </script>
</head>
```

**Update 7/31/17:**

I have taken the advice of Alex and Chetan and re-written the code to use only ADO.Net with SQL Connections and Commands. I can now assign variables to the previous recordset objRs stored procedure variable (now a SqlCommand) using SqlDataReader.

Comment: You're using `()` where it looks like you should be using `[]` as an indexer.

Comment: You seem to be mixing ADODB via COM & OleDbConnection? If you are using SQL Server you should stick to SqlConnection/SqlCommand etc - the latter is vital as currently you have a huge SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: I tried using 'strap = objRs["strap"];' but I still received an error message.

Comment: You need to correct your course and choose right template for application,  either asp.net webforms or asp.net mvc. For this particular problem you better switch to ADO.NET which has far better features to perform database operations with SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the advice of Alex and Chetan and re-written the code to use only ADO.Net with SQL Connections and Commands. I can now assign variables to the previous recordset objRs stored procedure variable (now a SqlCommand) using SqlDataReader.